# Do multiple forms in an ASP.NET MVC view conflict?

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

Given an MVC view like so:

```
<form id="Form1">
    <label for="LastName">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LastName)
    </label>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName)
    <button id="SubmitOne" onclick="SubmitOne_Click()">SubmitOne</button>
</form>

<form id="Form2">
    <label for="LastName2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LastName2)
    </label>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName2)
    <button id="SubmitTwo" onclick="SubmitTwo_Click()">SubmitTwo</button>
</form>

The javascript functions are irrelevant, this problem also occurs when they are empty or just have an alert.
```

When SubmitOne is clicked, everything works as expected. However, when SubmitTwo is clicked the whole page refreshes, which isn't supposed to happen. If I comment out Form1, then Form2 works fine.

What is going on here?

**Update:** Here's the javascript:

```
function SubmitOne_Click() {
    alert("One");
}

function SubmitTwo_Click() {
    alert("Two");
}
```

As a troubleshooting step, I stripped the view down to nothing but the form, and the script down to nothing as well. I do have references to Bootstrap, jqGrid, and jQuery in the _Layout, but nothing that currently uses them in this view.

Comment: Except, form1 doesn't. Are forms the wrong way to be doing this? I really just need local interaction with the fields. Thanks.

Comment: It appears that the comment I replied to above has been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to add a type attribute to my buttons:

```
<button type="button" id="SubmitTwo" onclick="SubmitTwo_Click()">SubmitTwo</button>
```

This prevented the button from doing a full submit of the form.

See also: [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that.  Nice job of solving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple forms on the page does not cause any issues unless they are nested, which is not your case. I bet the issue is indeed in the JavaScript.

Please show us relevant JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have nested forms,  You don't have same ID,  You don't have same of anything. ( So that is good)

Please post your javascript code and also,  be nice to peek at your razor form code along with your controller methods